# Reading a .parquet.gz , gzipped parquet file in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, gzip, parquet

Hi i am trying to read parquet file which has been compressed and saved as sample.parquet.gz file in spark , if someone can tell me how to do that ?

PS-  I understand  i can easily read gz.parquet file in spark but i want to read a parquet which is commpressed using gzip

Comment: What is the difference between `gz.parquet` and `parquet.gz` in your wording? Compression is normally internal to the Parquet format and it should not make a difference which codec you used.

Comment: Take a scenario -. You saved  file df.write.parquet('./sample.parquet')  and then you compress this file as sample.parquet.gz           while if you use df.write.option('compression','gzip').parquet('sample.gzip.parquet:).  In this. Data is first compressed and they stored as parquet

Answer (score 0):

```py
df = spark.read.parquet("/mnt/datalake/xxxxxx/Xxxxxx/Packed-Files/zipFileName.gz")
```

This worked for me.